# Visual Basic .NET (Easy way to test Form)

Tags: visual-studio

I have been using Java for most of my programming projects, but I got Visual Studio yesterday and want to start learning how to use Visual Basic.

Normally in Java, I can just copy and paste code into the class and rename the class name and it will work.

However, in Visual Basic, this doesn't seem to be as simple as just a copy and paste and rename. All of Visual Basic .NET code is in a solution, and from what I can tell, there is only a main method in one form. In Java, you can have a main class in each class and run the class simple like that.

I thought that you could do it the same way in Visual Basic .NET, but so far, I have not been able to find the way to do it. I have tried making a form and then pasting in the example code into the load form, and that seemed to generate no errors but didn't work neither.

```
Public Class GridsAndData

    Private Sub GridsAndData_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
        Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
        formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 200, 400, 200, 200)
        myPen.Dispose()
        formGraphics.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This was some sample code that I tried to draw a single line on a form.

Comment: I clicked on the project properties but didn't see the lighting bolt that shows the properties. The only way that I could see the properties was with the form highlighted and that showed all the properties that is associated with click and double click. it compiles and will run but for example if you have 5 forms in a project and you just want to test compile and run form 2 without all of the other forms can this be set as the main entry point. I would image it can, but I just cannot see it on the solution properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to draw anywhere except in the `Paint` handler in Windows. Here's an example that works with the code you posted (placed in the correct method):

Start a new WinForms solution (**File->New Project** from the main menu).

Once the project is created, click on the **Properties** window (by default in the lower-right corner of Visual Studio). Click on the **Events** button (the little lightning bolt) to switch to that tab. Find the **Paint** item (in the **Appearance** section), and double-click it.

Paste your code into the generated method (which, by default, is `Form1_Paint`):

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    ' Paste your code here - the part below "Private Sub" and above "End Sub"
    Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
    Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
    formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 200, 400, 200, 200)
    myPen.Dispose()
    formGraphics.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: I might have asked this before, but in Java you can easily paste in a class from stackoverflow and then put the main method in and compile and test the class. This doesn't seem so easy in Visual Basic .NET is there a simple way to do that. If I find code that is a console or class can I just create a new class in Visual Basic .NET and paste in the code and "click" compile. This is easy in Java but I haven't used .NET visual basic all that much so I am somewhat at a lose on how this can actually be done.